# How to return random records in a table based on query results?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table named Values with thousands of records (sample is a lot less). The data itself is unique except that some records share the same ID.

So I need a query to return random records depending on the total count of TestQ1. For example, the query has a total of 9 records for ID 120 so there should be 3 random records each time this query is run because that's what the Test table indicates (this table changes the "Test" numbers weekly).

Pictured:

The "Values" table is the raw data.
The "TestQ1" query has a total count for that specific "ID"
and to the right, is the number of records that should be returned.
[image]

This is as far as I've been able to get:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Values.ID, Values.Test, Values.State, Rnd([Values]![ID]) AS [Random No], * FROM [Values] ORDER BY Rnd([Values]![ID]);
```

Comment: You will also need a _unique ID_. That you could get by appending the records of table Values to a table having an _Autonumber_ field set to _Random_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TOP N cannot be dynamic in a query object.

Can calculate a group sequence ID and use that in criteria to return a number of records for each ID group. That requires a unique identifier field which can be provided with an autonumber. Set it as random so the selection can be different as records are added to dataset.

Consider SQL:

```
SELECT Values.PKID, Values.ID, Values.Test, Values.State, DCount("*","Values","ID=" & [Values].[ID] & " AND PKID<" & [PKID])+1 AS GrpSeq
FROM TestQ2 INNER JOIN [Values] ON TestQ2.ID = Values.ID
WHERE (((DCount("*","Values","ID=" & [Values].[ID] & " AND PKID<" & [PKID])+1)<=[TestQ2].[Test]));
```

However, if you truly need to return randomized set of records with each query run, I expect VBA will be needed. Either to populate a field in Values table with a randomized sequence number for each ID group or to populate a temp table with randomized dataset. Consider VBA to populate field:

```
Sub RandomSeq()
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset, rs2 As DAO.Recordset, x As Integer
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [Values]")
Do While Not rs1.EOF
    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Values] WHERE ID=" & rs1!ID & " ORDER BY Rnd([ID]);")
    Do While Not rs2.EOF
        rs2.Edit
        x = x + 1
        rs2!GrpSeq = x
        rs2.Update
        rs2.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs2.Close
    x = 0
    rs1.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Now run query:

```
SELECT Values.ID, Values.Test, Values.State, Values.GrpSeq
FROM TestQ2 INNER JOIN [Values] ON TestQ2.ID = Values.ID
WHERE (((Values.GrpSeq)<=[TestQ2].[Test]));
```

Be aware this will not be practical in a split database with multiple simultaneous users. Then a temp table (located in frontend) approach may be needed.

Comment: I jumped the gun a bit - I run the query and get:

"The Specified Field 'Values.PKID' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement".

I'm a bit lost - not sure why that error message is being returned.

Comment: Possibly has to do with TestQ2 used in query. This would mean the Values.PKID field would be pulled in from two sources. I did not know the SQL for TestQ2 so I used a table in lieu of query. Use an alias name for PKID field in TestQ2 so it will be different than field name in Values table in final query.

Comment: Actually, if PKID field is not included in TestQ2 query, this error should not occur and I am at a loss as to cause.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck - no clue. I went back and not sure why I get that error either.

Comment: Both of your suggestions work, I appreciate the time you put into this.

Comment: Curious, for the VBA, do I need to add a field as I did for SQL? The reason I ask is that when I run the VBA I get a "Run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection."

Comment: Yes, need to add a field in table that can be populated by the code. Just a long integer number type. I used GrpSeq for name.